# Obscure text using Tkinter's insert method

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been going through the `Tkinter` documentation to create an entry that will be used to enter a password.

Snippet:

```
code = Entry(frame, width=25, fg='Black', border=0, bg='White', font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light', 11))
code.place(x=30,y=150)
code.insert(0,'password')
```

This works well in showing the word 'password'

[image: enter link description here]

However, I would like to hide the text when I start to type.

I can add the syntax `show="*"` in the `code = Entry` line of text, however, this will then change the default text for the 'password'.

I've tried to put the `show="*"` within the `code.insert` but I either get an error or the text is not hidden.

Is this a possible scenario?

Hopefully this all makes sense?

Comment: It will hide the entered password ```bullet = "\u2022" #specifies bullet character
code = Entry(frame,show=bullet)``` and add ```show = '*' while creating Entry..

Comment: Make a normal `Entry` and then when the user clicks on it/starts typing, use `<Entry>.config(show="*")`. You can do that by using `.bind("<FocusIn>", <function>)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_enter(e):
    code.delete(0, 'end')
    code.config(show="*")


def on_leave(e):
    name= code.get()
    if name=='':
        code.insert(0,'password')

code = Entry(frame, width=25, fg='Black', border=0, bg='White', font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light', 11))`enter code here`
code.place(x=30,y=150)
code.insert(0,'password')
code.bind('<FocusIn>', on_enter)
code.bind('<FocusOut>', on_leave)
```

Comment: You need to set `show=""` if placeholder need to be shown, otherwise the placeholder will be all "*".